# Работа с асинхронными задачами, возвращающими значения

Tags: c#, многопоточность, android-asynctask

Как правильно работать с методом, который в качестве аргумента принимает асинхронную задачу например `Task<NpgsqlConnection>` ? Допустим у меня есть асинхронный метод :

```
    public async Task<NpgsqlConnection> CreateConnectionAsync()
    {
        var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        return connection;
    }
```

И мне нужно получить обьект `NpgsqlConnection` вот в такой метод, который для подключения создает команду.

```
    public  NpgsqlCommand NpgCommandCreator(NpgsqlConnection connection, string commandtext)
    {
        using (var connector = connection)
        {
            NpgsqlCommand COMMAND =  connector.CreateCommand();
            COMMAND.CommandText = commandtext;
            return COMMAND;
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что `NpgsqlConnection` и `Task<NpgsqlConnection>` не одно и то же, как мне модифицировать `NpgCommandCreator` что бы он смог работать с обьектом возвращаемым от `CreateConnectionAsync` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как ваш метод `CreateConnectionAsync` возвращает `Task<NpgsqlConnection>` можно ничего не модернизировать, а достаточно дождаться выполнения асинхронной операции используя оператор `await`, после чего передать полученное значение методу `NpgCommandCreator`.

> если `await` применяется к результату вызова метода, который возвращает `Task<TResult>`, то типом выражения `await` является `TResult`

Например, так:

```
public async void DoWorkAsync()
{
   // Дожидаемся выполнения асинхронной операции.
   // после ее завершения в переменной будет объект типа NpgsqlConnection.
   var connection = await CreateConnectionAsync();

   var myCommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Users";

   // Передаем  данный объект в метод.
   var command = NpgCommandCreator(connection, myCommandText);
}
```

Comment: В данном случае выполняется асинхронно подключение, а выполнение запроса синхронно. Вполне возможно что выполнение запроса тоже нужно выполнить асинхронно.

Comment: @TylerDurden а где вы здесь увидели выполнение запроса? Сначала создается соединение, потом создается команда, которая будет выполнена в рамках указанного соединения. Но команда при этом не запускается на выполнение.

Comment: При передаче соединения 'NpgCommandCreator',я предположил о выполнении запроса, я не прав (преждевременное суждение)

Answer (score 1):

При создании методов по моделе async/await вся цепочка вызовов должна создаваться по моделе async/await. Иными словами async/await **должен** быть **сквозным**.
Например

```
async Task<int> FirstMethod()
{
  await Task.Delay(100);
  return 1;
}
async Task<int> SecondMethod()
{
  await Task.Delay(100);
  return 2;
}
async Task<int> UseBothMethods()
{
  var first = await FirstMethod();//Текущий поток высвобождается и может заняться чем-то еще, пока FirstMethod() не вернет значение
  var second = await SecondMethod();Текущий поток высвобождается и может заняться чем-то еще, пока SecondMethod() не вернет значение
  return first+second;
}
```

Если метод UseBothMethods создать без использования async/await, то нам придется дожидаться выполнения FirstMethod и SecondMethod, тем самым подвешивая(замораживая) поток выполнения.

```
Task<int> UseBothMethods()
{
  var first = FirstMethod().Result; // ждем 100 мс пока выполниться метод. Поток заморожен и ничего не делает
  var second = SecondMethod().Result;// ждем 100 мс пока выполниться метод. Поток заморожен и ничего не делает
  return first+second;
}
```

Если async/await не делать сквозным, то это будет нарушением использования паттерна и лишит нас выгоды от асинхронного ожидания выполнения "долгих" методов, которая заключается  в высвобождение потока для выполнения какой-либо работы.
Теперь поясню как это все относится к текущему вопросу. Отвечаю, если создавать async/await сквозным, как это и положено, то вопросы по типу того, какой возник у автора, попросту не будут возникать.